# Multiple regex query (Notepad++)

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I’ve understand that I can do multiple search&replace queries in this way:

Search: (á)|(é)|(í)|(ó)|(ú)

Replace: (?1Á)(?2É)(?3Í)(?4Ó)(?5Ú)

Example:

Before: ***á***rbol **á**cido

After: ***Á***rbol **á**cido

But how can I use this method if I need to add a precondition, such as line start and some punctuation before it?

I’ve tried:

Search: `(^[—¿¡«]*?)[(á)|(é)|(í)|(ó)|(ú)]` => Works!

Replace: `\1(?2Á)(?3É)(?4Í)(?5Ó)(?6Ú)` => Doesn’t work…

Example:

Before: *—¿**á**rbol **á**cido?*

After: *—¿rbol **á**cido?*

Any help?

Regards.

Comment: Why do you suddenly use a `[]` character class in your second sample? Get rid of it.

Comment: If I don't add [], the precondition only affects the first argument (in this case, '(á)'). If I add the precondition to each argument, I will exceed the limit of 10 arguments to refer to.

Comment: Use a non-capturing group for mere grouping purpose, character class is the wrong tool here. `(^[—¿¡«]*?)(?:(á)|(é)|(í)|(ó)|(ú))`

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second regex, you use a character class (indicated by `[...]`) - for grouping purposes according to a comment. But that's not how those work. Use non-capturing groups instead, e.g.

```
(^[—¿¡«]*?)(?:(á)|(é)|(í)|(ó)|(ú))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a group for each character, you can also have all the characters in one group and replace them with their uppercase variant.

- search string

  ```
  (^[—¿¡«]*)([áéíóú])
  ```
- replacement

  ```
  $1\U$2
  ```

The following can be found in the [Notepad++ Regular Expressions documentation](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Substitutions):

> `\U` Causes next characters to be output in uppercase, until a `\E` is found.

Comment: Thanks, Johan, but Notepad++ doesn't understand that **'Á'** (or any of the others) is the capital of **'á'**.

Comment: Ah, I thought it would. I'll delete this answer then.